# Title gets cut when using TabPageIndicator

Tags: java, android

I am using TabPageIndicator in a fragment and sometimes the text gets cut off. Is this possible to adjust somehow? In the example below the complete title is "역사/문화/종교" but it just displays "역사/문화/". When localizing the app then this occurs at various tabs throughout the application.

[image]

XML

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"/>
```

JAVA

```
public class SearchResultActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private TabPageIndicator indicator;
private ViewPager pager;

String mCity;

private static final String[] tabTitle = new String[] {"쇼핑", "역사/문화/종교", "자연/휴양", "전망", "오락시설"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mCity = intent.getExtras().getString("mCity");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_bg_background);

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return SearchResultFragment.newInstance(tabTitle[position % tabTitle.length], mCity);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitle[position % tabTitle.length].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitle.length;
    }
}}
```